# When is the lock released if I return from the synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am confused over the point at which the lock is released if I have a return statement from the synchronized block; to find that out I have added try-finally block and added a sysout inside finally block printing 'lock released' but I can clearly see that before even that 'release' statement is printed, the 2nd thread has already obtained the lock. When is the lock released? what is the guarantee that things don't get messier?

```
public static int testClassLevelMonitor() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
    synchronized(TestLocks.class) {
        System.out.println("Static Block : Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -- have the lock");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        return 0;
    }
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Static Block : Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -- released the lock");
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
}
```

> Static Block : Thread pool-1-thread-1 -- have the lock
>
> Static Block : Thread pool-1-thread-2 -- have the lock
>
> Static Block : Thread pool-1-thread-1 -- released the lock
>
> Static Block : Thread pool-1-thread-2 -- released the lock

Comment: The lock can be released as soon as the block it protects is finished which means after the return but before the finalized block. That does not mean that the jvm is not allowed to keep the lock a bit longer if it thinks it will improve performance.

Comment: When one thread reaches the `finally` block, it has released the lock. At this time you don’t comtrol the order of events. Either the next thread may acquire the lock and print its output from the synchronized block first; or the first thread may print its message from the `finally` block first. You have no way of knowing the order in advance.

Comment: You have not posted the `TestLocks.java` and also how you're creating `thread-1` and `thread-2`? My strongest suspicion is `testClassLevelMonitor()` synchronized method obtains lock on the object that the method is being run on, but there are two different thread objects calling it.

Comment: @fabfas, there are no objects involved here; it is a static method and lock is obtained at the class level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `synchronized` statement is specified in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19).

> ```
> SynchronizedStatement:  
>     synchronized ( Expression ) Block
> ```
>
> - [..]
> - Otherwise, let the non-null value of the `Expression` be `V`. The executing thread locks the monitor associated with `V`. Then the `Block`
>     is executed, and then there is a choice:
>
>   - If execution of the `Block` completes normally, then the monitor is unlocked and the `synchronized` statement completes normally.
>   - **If execution of the `Block` completes abruptly for any reason, then the monitor is unlocked and the `synchronized` statement [completes
>       abruptly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) (`return` completes abruptly) for the same reason.**

In other words, the lock is only held for the length of the body of the `synchronized` statement.

```
System.out.println("Static Block : Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -- have the lock");
Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
return 0;
```

The `finally` block will execute without holding the lock.

---

While holding the lock, the executing thread will push the result of evaluating the `return` statement onto the stack, **release the lock**, execute the `finally` block, then return the value.